# iPad buttons near bottom of screen not detecting tap

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uibutton, nslayoutconstraint

I've a view with three buttons near the bottom of the screen. The problem is that the buttons are not tappable. If I move the buttons a little bit higher, they detect tap events.

Following are screens of my view and the view in the visual debugger.

Currently the `bottom constraint = 25`. At this constraint, half of the button is tappable. If I move it lower, it does not detect any taps, and if I move it higher, then the whole button becomes tappable.

I cannot show the complete view heirarchy of the app because it is very complex. This View containing the buttons is added as a childViewContainer on another viewContainer which itself is added as a chidldViewContainer.

[image: Here you can see the constraints applied to the buttons]

[image: This is the actual view of the buttons]

[image: These are the wireframes in the visual debugger(The line across the buttons in a view behind the buttons, not infront of them)]

[image: Here you can see that the buttons are at the top of the view heirarchy]

Comment: Can you check whether these buttons are fully on top of their parent container view? If not only the portion which comes over the parent container view will respond to touch event

Comment: @Arun the last screenshot that I posted confirms that they are on the top, the items at the bottom left corner of the image are the buttons, and they are at the top

Comment: If the line in the image provided, which runs over the buttons is its parent container view, only the portion to the top of the line will respond to touch event

Comment: Can you just verify this for all of the parent views of the button? As you said the parent of buttons is again child of another view, check for all the views

Comment: @Arun yes it's on top of all the views, I did not post the complete image because it is quite complex, and the line that runs across the buttons is actually a view that is behind these buttons, I wrote this in the description of the images, don't know where the description is posted

Comment: The strange this is that if I move the buttons 10 points higher, then the entire buttons become tappable, I don't change anything else other than moving the buttons higher

Comment: Only a portion of the button is not responding or the entire button won't respond?

Comment: At their current postion, the one that is shown in the images, half of the button responds, if I move them lower, the entire button becomes unresponsive to touch, and if I move them a bit higher, the entire button becomes responsive

Comment: I seriously doubt the issue you are facing is what I have mentioned. Your buttons are not fully on top of any of its parent view. I have experienced such issue a lot and wasted hours trying to figure out the issue. Please verify all the parent views of buttons

Comment: @Arun ok thanks for the suggestion, I'll have another look